# Add list elements to csv

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I have created various lists and would like to write them to a csv file.
That means there is
List A
List B
List C
List D - and so on

I tried to summarize the lists as follows

```
adress_label = [Anrede.anrede[0], Titel.titel[0], Name.vorname[0], Name.nachname[0], Adress_zus.adress_zus[0],
            Strasse.strasse[0], str(PLZ.plz[0]), Stadt.stadt[0]]


with open('adress_list.csv', 'w') as adress_list:
    adress_writer = csv.writer(adress_list, delimiter=',', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

adress_writer.writerow(adress_label)
```

However, the result is not written correctly to the csv file.
The results of the various lists are written in 1 column instead of 1 column per list element.

Unfortunately I have not found an answer to my question here in the forum.
How can I add different list elements to a csv file in Python?

Comment: in your code example you only write the label into file and that works for me without a problem. (btw fix your ident in your question)

Comment: Please print some of the data in your list.

You may be interested in using pandas and the to_csv function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example to help you understand better how it works.Using `writer.writerow` you print data to csv per column, using `writer.writerows` you print data per row.Also, `zip` is an iterator of multiple lists.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

listA = [ {"name":"Text1","age":30},{"name":"Text4","age":20} ]
listB = [ {"name":"Text2","age":40},{"name":"Text5","age":35} ]
listC = [ {"name":"Text3","age":50},{"name":"Text6","age":70} ]

with open('address_list.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for (a,b,c) in zip(listA,listB,listC):
        writer.writerow([a['name']])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however
my main problem is:

How do I write different lists in different columns in the csv?
There is a value in each list. And each value should be in one column.

Comment: @pythonHD in my answer i have 3 lists add 4th one for your case

Comment: I modified the solution and now my program works.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @pythonHD next time try to ask question according to site standards [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)